# After installing QtCreator, lightdm not turn on xubuntu 14.02

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, lightdm, qt-creator

I just simply wrote `sudo apt-get install qtcreator` in terminal and saw how he removing xserver and some graphical packages in installation process.
At the end, he install them again, but after reboot, lightdm (desktop service) don't want to start (blank screen).
What I need to do, to fix that?
Tried to reinstall lightdm but doesn't help.

Comment: It could be that Xserver is not starting. please press Ctrl + Alt + F1 , log in and type 'startx' .Please leave a comment wether your desktop appeared or not.

Comment: After `sudo startx` black screen appear again for about 1 minute. When it's back to terminal, the last info is: `xinit: connection to the xserver lost`

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have? Have you installed any drivers manually?

Comment: GTX660M, I install newest Nvidia graphic drivers (352) from repo. All working perfectly by month till that qtcreator installation.

Comment: Ok, this is very awkward.Upvoted your question in hope of somebody else finding a good answer because i certainly don't know what may be causing this, especially if you have reinstalled lightdm. However, i do have some ideas:    1: Have you already removed qtcreator and tried rebooting?   2: try `sudo start lightdm`   3: if you have lost all hope connect to an external drive and copy all your data, then reinstall xubuntu.  However you probably tried this, so really, i have no more ideas.

Comment: Fix is purge all nvidia stuff `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`. Then remove all .Xauth files from home catalog. `sudo rm -r ~/.Xauth*`
Reboot and it will work again on delivered open source drivers.
Any next installation of Nvidia drivers (I tried 3 different version) will crash Xserver again.
Remove Qt doesn't fix problem.
That wasn't first big problem with Xubuntu, so after backup data, I switched to Mint (and here all working perfectly but a bit slower).
Thanks for help.